# Jupyter не открывается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains, jupyter-notebook

Пытаюсь открыть jupyter notebook в pycharm (версия professional)

Поставил пакет jupyter, на рабочем ПК все хорошо, на домашнем выдает следующее

1) `t.ipynb` - внутри папки `analyze`
[image: t.ipynb]

2) `q.ipynb` - внутри папки проекта пишет уже, что пакет не установлен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну добавьте файл к проекту

Comment: @Александр,  Вас не затруднит подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: А он точно установлен? В pip freeze он есть?

Comment: Да. Через settings если смотреть там в project interpreter есть Jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) t.ipynb - внутри папки analyze

`analyze` судя по всему виртуальное окружение - не нужно в нем ничего хранить, как минимум эта директория по умолчанию исключена из индексации (оранжевая иконка папки), как максимум вы будете получать подобные ошибки. Если виртуальное окружение не используется, то его имеет смысл удалить.

> 2) q.ipynb - внутри папки проекта пишет уже, что пакет не установлен

Проверьте что в **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Jupyter | Jupyter Server** указан проектный интерпретатор с установленным Jupyter.